# How to find the source of students' plagiarized code

Tags: plagiarism-detection

I teach programming in high school. In the past, when I looked at a program and knew it was plagiarized, I could google the name of the program (e.g. name of a common game) and **track down the code**, and sometimes I could literally google some lines of the code and **find the source**. That doesn't work anymore. Lines of code just turn up nothing, and names often result in dozens of youtube tutorials.
*Please note, I'm not looking for tools to compare two snippets of code.* I'm looking for ways to search for code online that matches my student's code that I believe is plagiarized. Most of the plagiarized code I see is in either python or c++.

I would be so grateful if there's someone out there who can help me outsmart my cheaters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Similar code detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912349/similar-code-detector)

Answer (score 0):

[My teachers were using this](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eaiken/moss/) and it worked pretty good, if that can help. (Although it doesn't detect the source, only tells if there are similarities from what I know)

Comment: Yup. This software basically checks for AST similarities between the code I believe, instead of matching variable/function/type names. My university used it as well.

Comment: Nope. I'm talking about reading code and immediately recognizing that this kid did not write this code. More often than not, they found a program online, made a copy, and turned it in. It helps a lot in confronting the kid if I can find the source. I'm fine with my own ability to judge whether there's a match, once I find it. (I taught English in the distant past).